# Не получается сделать миграцию. Как правильно сделать миграцию в django? ошибка: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python, django, sqlite3, миграция

Использую команду `python manage.py makemigrations`. Пробовал удалить db.sqlite3 и повторить предыдущую команду. В приложении Review не создается каталог с миграциями. Пробовал добавить этот каталог с другого приложения без лишних миграций и повторить команду. Ничего из перечисленного не помогло.  Выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Review_keywords

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 453, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\System\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    path('distrib/', include('Review.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\Review\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\Review\views.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .forms import *
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\Review\forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    class AddArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\Review\forms.py", line 17, in AddArticleForm
    class Meta:
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\System\Review\forms.py", line 27, in Meta
    'keywords': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=list(Keywords.objects.all()))
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 398, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 91, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\1392680\Documents\newnewSystem\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Review_keywords
```

Таблица Keywords есть в models.py

```
class Keywords(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='Key words')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, я вызываю в файлe forms.py: Keywords.objects.all(). Пришлось закомментировать эту строку, а потом уже сделать миграции.
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

Все получилось.